# TinyMCE custom url converter

Tags: javascript, url, tinymce, tinymce-4

I am trying to change the url  when inserting images to the editor , my problem is that all urls are changed , what I am looking for is to change the url for the img dom only .

my code so far :

```
function customURLConverter(url, node, on_save, name) {
    if(url.indexOf("/advanced/frontend/web") == -1)
    url = "/advanced/frontend/web"+url;
    return url;
}


tinyMCE.init({
        urlconverter_callback : "customURLConverter"
});
```

Comment: fourth parameter is not  exist !

Comment: yes I typed by mistake , so how to solve my problem there is any suggestions

Comment: i'm not very clear what you expect. please update the question clearly

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: Please create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).